# Joomla 2.5 - Phocagallery - Error: You are not authorized to do this action

Tags: joomla

After updating Joomla from 1.6 to 2.5 (I updated all the plug-ins too) I can't see my galleries anymore. Every time I click on a picture, the following message appears:

> "You are not authorized to do this action Please login."

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

Go to Extensions Manager->Database->Fix.

Then clear joomla/browser cache.

If it does not solve your problem re-install Phocagallery (but select fresh install option on prompt)

Also you may find instructions for migrating from 1.5/1.6 to 2.x

http://www.phoca.cz/documents/50-phoca/566-how-to-migrate-extensions-from-joomla-15-to-joomla-25

Comment: RESOLVED:
I DID!!!!
I hope it can be useful for someone. I just set * in the field "language" of the table phocagallery.
The field was empty. My site uses only one language (italian).

Thank you for your assistance